# Shopify Facebook Pixel AddToCart Event firing Twice

Tags: facebook, shopify, pixel, facebook-pixel

I have a problem with my Shopify site Facebook Pixel witch connected via the admin area firing twice for AddToCart event. I have installed GA and GTM but they don't have AddToCart events.

Every time after pressing the button 'Add to Cart' event firing twice and I can see in FB Pixel dashboard the same date and time for that event. Also, [Facebook Pixel Helper](https://www.screencast.com/t/Kv3rt3shNM) said 'The Facebook pixel activated 2 times on this web page, which can cause errors in your event tracking.'

[A page for testing](https://greatjonesgoods.com/products/big-deal)

Guys, can you give hints what is wrong, I have already tried all the options
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? I saw your page for testing shows only 1 AddToCart event firing. Care to share where the problem might be for someone else? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, yes the problem was resolved. I found the problem with my theme file snippets/ajaxify-cart.liquid looks like ajax works incorrectly after some experementation.